# Bash single-line nested for-loop is taking comparison variable as a command

Tags: bash

I believe my error is in `do if ($i -gt 100)` area but I havent been able to figure it out.

My input is:

```
for i in `ps | cut -d ' ' -f1`; do if ($i -gt 100); then echo $i; fi; done
```

My output is this where the process IDs have been taken as commands.

```
bash: 13968: command not found
bash: 21732: command not found
bash: 21733: command not found
bash: 21734: command not found
```

How can I fix this and what is the relevant man page that I should read up on? Thank you.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-shift, https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs, https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping

Comment: What is your script supposed to do?

Comment: As your answer stated, it is to list all PIDs that are greater than 100. It was just a practice exercise in response to a comment made by Jeffrey Snover. Your solution is obviously the better one but I'm just trying to get better at bash scripting so fixing my syntax was more important to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($i -gt 100)
```

should be changed to

```
if [ $i -gt 100 ]
```

Note that there is a space before and after `[]`, this is neccessary, otherwise you will get a syntax error (its because `[` is a link to `test` in `/usr/bin`).

The relevant manapge would be `man test`, as `[` is `test`.

Also, but this has nothing to do with the question, I recommend switchting from

```
`command`
```

to

```
$(command)
```

in bash.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what your script is trying to do (the posted answers produce no output on my system) but if you want to print all PIDs that are greater than 100, here's how you'd do that:

```
$ ps | awk '$1 > 100{print $1}'
PID
314024
217880
230804
217084
263048
260788
218016
313464
201556
200732
```

Answer (score 0):

just add spaces after and before brackets and the expression

```
for i in `ps | cut -d ' ' -f1`; do if [ $i -gt 100 ]; then echo $i; fi; done
```